# Very strange behavior with grep and IFS

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, wildcards, quoting

I'm having trouble using grep, the returned results are "n-empty", I mean without the 'n' character...

This is the script sample :

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="\\n"

i=$(grep -ril $1 *)

echo $i

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I tried with `IFS='\n'` and `IFS="\n"` but the result displays the correct pathes *only* when I get rid of the IFS...

I'm using the result in a `for theFile in $i; do......done` loop, where **the results are used in the right way and `theFile` is correctly displayed**.

The only problem is that I have no correct console/file output of `$i`, which is a strategic data :

What I'm seeing in the console and the file which is written (sample) :

`LecteurSy dicatio _sy dic/fiche_93.xml`

What should be displayed and written (sample) :

`LecteurSyndication_syndic/fiche_93.xml`

Any idea ?

**EDIT : complete script to play at home ;)**

```
#!/bin/bash

monTerminal=$(tty) ; monTerminal=${monTerminal:9}
fichier="/home/importts/tmpCmdOpenFirst$monTerminal.xml"

PWD="`pwd`"
echo "== Recherche dans les fiches  ==" > "$fichier"

echo "Recherche : $1" >> "$fichier"
echo "Dans      : $PWD" >> "$fichier"

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="\\n"

i=$(grep -ril $1 *)

echo $i

echo "== Liste des fichiers trouves ==" >> "$fichier"

echo $i >> "$fichier"

IFS=$OLDIFS


#while read uneFiche
for uneFiche in $i;
do

echo "================================" >> "$fichier"
echo "== $uneFiche" >> "$fichier"
echo "================================" >> "$fichier"
echo "" >> "$fichier"

xmlindent "$uneFiche" >> "$fichier"

done < /home/robert/tmpCmdOpenFirst_liste.txt

nano "$fichier"
#rm $fichier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've set `IFS` to `\n`, not to a newline. In bash, you can use `$'…'` to have backslash sequences interpreted as control characters:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Or you have the portable option of using a literal newline.

```
IFS='
'
```

The second problem is that `IFS` matters when you expand a variable. So it needs to be set when `$i` is expanded, it doesn't actually matter when you set `i`.

```
i=$(grep -ril -e "$1" -- *)
set -f; OLDIFS="$IFS"; IFS='
'
for uneFiche in $i; do
  set +f; IFS="$OLDIFS"
  …
done
set +f; IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

Additionally, don't forget to quote variables when you aren't splitting, e.g. the pattern you pass to `grep`. In case the pattern starts with `-`, pass it to `grep` with the `-e` option. Also put `--` in front of the file names in case the first file name begins with `-`. Furthermore, in case a file name contains glob characters, turn off globbing with `set -f` before leaving a variable expansion unquoted.

A simpler approach would be to call `grep` on each file inside the loop. As an additional benefit, your script wouldn't break on file names containing newlines.

```
for uneFiche in *; do
  if grep -qri -e "$1" -- "$uneFiche"; then
    …
  fi
done
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `set +f; IFS="$OLDIFS"` in the loop : does it have any effect ?

Comment: @Benj In case wildcard expansion or `IFS` is used in the loop (not the case here, but they could be if the code evolves). I also reset them after the loop in case the expansion happens to be empty.

Comment: I deported the edit I made in a separate answer, I think it is more readable. You can delete the edit I made to your answer, or let me know what is the more readable way.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to follow your problem description. The only useful information is missing, that is the output of `grep -ril $1 *` (or rather a sample of that) and an explanation what the problem is. I assume the problem is whitespace in some paths.

*EDIT : There is the sample you requested :*

*The blanks are indeed 'n' chars...*

```
1_LecteurSy dicatio _sy dic/fiche_174.xml
2_Tra sformatio XSL_tif/fiche_174.xml
3_CorrigerTIF_cor/fiche_174.xml
4_Tra sformatio XSL_ge /fiche_174.xml
```

*/EDIT*

`IFS="\\n"` is obviously wrong as you can easily check with `echo "\\n"`. I am not even sure whether `\n` works in IFS definition. Use IFS=$'\n' instead or

```
IFS="
"
```

*EDIT*

The $'\n' form does not solve the problem. The "blank line" form makes things appear correctly, but the results are no more presented as a list (one per line).
I keep the 'blank line' form since its result is roughly what I need.

*/EDIT*

Setting IFS does not make sense to me if you restore it before the `for uneFiche in $i` line. This way you just influence the line `echo $i >> "$fichier"` and that would have been a lot easier by quoting: `i="$(grep -ril $1 *)"`, `echo "$i" >> "$fichier"`

*EDIT*

`i="$(grep -ril $1 *)"` seems not to have any effect.

*/EDIT*

If you have such problems with whitespace and word splitting then it might be easier to work with a pipeline like this:

```
grep -ril --null -- "$1" * | xargs -0 /my/script.sh
```

with `/my/script.sh` being

```
#!/bin/bash
fichier="/home/importts/tmpCmdOpenFirst$monTerminal.xml"

for uneFiche in "$@"; do
    echo "================================"
    echo "== $uneFiche"
    echo "================================"
    echo

xmlindent "$uneFiche"

done >> "$fichier"
```

Comment: Reply to @HaukeLaging Since your answer is quite consequent, I answered by editing it, step by step.

Comment: @Benj No, no... I meant you should have started with the problem you were going to solve. Your initial problem hardly were the missing "n" which are a result of your trial to solve the former problem. So what about the output if you use the quotes as I showed you?

Comment: The `echo` sample I put in the first Edit is the direct `echo` of `$i`. I very appreciate your help, thanks :).

Comment: @Benj Of course, quoting in one place does not change the result. It doesn't matter where the word splitting occurs. You have to quote both cases, `i=` **and** `echo`.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

There is the final script which works, thanks to Gilles :

```
#!/bin/bash

# use a buffer file per terminal, permits multiple users
monTerminal=$(tty) ; monTerminal=${monTerminal:9}
fichier="........./tmpCmdFiche$monTerminal.xml"

PWD="`pwd`"
echo "== Recherche dans les fiches  ==" > "$fichier"

echo "Recherche : $1" >> "$fichier"
echo "Dans      : $PWD" >> "$fichier"

i=$(grep -ril -e "$1" -- *)

set -f
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS='
'

echo "== Liste des fichiers trouves ==" >> "$fichier"

echo "$i" >> "$fichier"

for uneFiche in $i; do

set +f; IFS="$OLDIFS"

echo "================================" >> "$fichier"
echo "== $uneFiche" >> "$fichier"
echo "================================" >> "$fichier"
echo "" >> "$fichier"

xmlindent "$uneFiche" >> "$fichier"

done < ............/tmpCmdOpenFirst_liste.txt

set +f
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```

And then a sample of the `cmdFiche somethingsosearch` command result :

```
== Recherche dans les fiches  ==
Recherche : somethingsosearch
Dans      : ............/XMLs/.........
== Liste des fichiers trouves ==
1_ImportationZip_zip/file2.xml
2_ImportationSuppSyndication_syndic/file19.xml
3_ModifierOrdreImages_ordre/fiche_44.xml
4_CorrigerPeriodesViaSyndication_periodes/fiche_44.xml
5_TransformationXSL_tif/fiche_44.xml
6_CorrigerRaisonSocialeViaSyndic_raisonsociale/fiche_44.xml
7_ExclureImportNoeuds_avantv2/fiche_44.xml
================================
== 1_ImportationZip_zip/file2.xml
================================

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<tif:OI xmlns:tif="http://www.tourinfrance.net/Tourinfrance3/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w$

    <!--Granule DublinCore-->

    <tif:DublinCore>
```

Awesome !